# #SQL - Order By matching record first

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i need help to order this table (named "season") , by matching actual date with the BEGINDATE

```
ID          NAME                 BEGINDATE
----------- -------------------- ----------
1           2014-2015            2014-10-01
2           2015-2016            2015-10-01
3           2016-2017            2016-10-01
4           2017-2018            2017-10-01
```

for example:
actual date is 2016/10/28 so we are in season 2016-2017 (id=3)
so the result should be

```
ID          NAME                 BEGINDATE
----------- -------------------- ----------
3           2016-2017            2016-10-01
1           2014-2015            2014-10-01
2           2015-2016            2015-10-01
4           2017-2018            2017-10-01
```

**UPDATE (SOLVED)**

what i finally did was:

```
DECLARE @IDACTIVE AS INT = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM SEASON WHERE BEGINDATE < GETDATE())

SELECT 
1 AS ORDERBY,
ID,
NAME,
BEGINDATE
FROM SEASON
WHERE ID = @IDACTIVE

UNION

SELECT 
2 AS ORDERBY,
ID,
NAME,
BEGINDATE
FROM SEASON
WHERE ID = @IDACTIVE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Follow the next approach:**

1) Get The only matched row by using `Top` and `Where` clauses.

2) Get the all records except the one that you getting on point #1

3) Combine the result of two Selects via using `UNION ALL`.

**Demo:-**

```
Create table season (id int , NAME varchar(20),BEGINDATE date)

go
insert into season values (1,'2014-2015','2014-10-01')
insert into season values (2,'2015-2016','2015-10-01')
insert into season values (3,'2016-2017','2016-10-01')
insert into season values (4,'2017-2018','2017-10-01')

go

select  * from (
    select top 1 * from season
    where BEGINDATE < getdate()
    order by BEGINDATE desc
) a

union all

select * from season 
where BEGINDATE != (
            select top 1 BEGINDATE from season
            where BEGINDATE < getdate()
            order by BEGINDATE desc)

-- an another Soluation 

select * from season
where DATEPART(Year,BEGINDATE) =DATEPART(Year,getdate())

union all

select * from season 
where DATEPART(Year,BEGINDATE) !=DATEPART(Year,getdate())
```

**The Result:**

[image]

Comment: If you add an explicit SortOrder column to each result set you can actually control the results. Your query here has no order by so the results being returned in a specific are by accident.

Comment: it works perfect! 
@SeanLange you are right, but in my case, the important is the first record.

Comment: @SeanLange -- I added another solution , kindly check and waiting ur feedback

Comment: The second solution just simply isn't going to work. You have top 1 but there is no order by. So if there are two rows that meet the where predicate you query may or may not work.

Comment: @SeanLange -- There is no need for top 1, so I deleted, and you are right about matching more than row from where clause, but on the other hand there is no retrieving more than row depends of business aspect (I am talking about season table logic )

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader . . . Although in practice, SQL Server returns the results from `union all`s sequentially, it is not guaranteed to do so.  It is really safest to always use `order by` to specify the ordering of a query.

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader although this article is about clustered indexes and ordering the same applies in this situation. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by.aspx

Comment: @SeanLange I appreciated this conversion , thanks bro.

Answer (score 0):

First move all future dates to the end, then order by beginDate

```
SELECT *
FROM season
ORDER BY CASE WHEN beginDate > GETDATE() THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
   beginDate
```

Comment: This is close but not quite there. If there are two rows with a beginDate > getdate() you have no way of knowing which one would be returned first.

Comment: The result set is not as the asker requested. -- check your result set form here: https://s14.postimg.org/u8u9q1ghd/Reeeeeeeeeeeee.png

Answer (score 0):

I think this is most easily done using window functions:

```
select s.*
from season s
order by (case when begindate = max(case when getdate() >= begindate then begindate end) over ()
               then 1 else 2
          end),
         id
```